# having multiple instance of same redux react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am building a react app with multi-widgets using react-redux every widget created dynamically.

I have an issue when update in the widget reflect in all other widgets.

is there any way to handle multi reducer to handle isolated data for every widget?

Reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const widgetReducer= (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_API':
            return { ...state, API: action.payload.API };
    }

    return state;
}

export default combineReducers({
    widget: widgetReducer
});
```

Actions

```
export const SetAPI = (data) => {
    return {
        type: "SET_API",
        payload: {
            API: data
        }
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers'
const store = createStore(reducers)
<Provider store={store}><Widget /></Provider>
```

Comment: If you are trying to create dynamic widgets, then your actions should be dynamic as well, shouldn't they?

Comment: until now they not.

Comment: @Shuvo I am trying to handle this but I need to figure out what is a good approach for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamic reducer for each widget is by assigning unique id for each new widget created and creating a new parent reducers as wrapper, something like:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const widgetReducer= (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_API':
            return { ...state, API: action.payload.API };
    }

    return state;
}

export widgetsContainerReducer(state = {}, action) {
   
   switch(action.type) {
    case 'SET_API':
    case 'WIDGET_ACTION_1':
    case 'WIDGET_ACTION_2': // other widget specific actions  
      const widgetId = action.payload.id;
   
      return {
        ...state,
        [widgetId]: widgetReducer(state[widgetId], action)
      }}
    default:
      return state;
   }
}

export default combineReducers({
    widgets: widgetsContainerReducer
});
```

Then have a widget id for every action specific to each widget:

```
export const SetAPI = (widgetId, data) => {
    return {
        type: "SET_API",
        payload: {
            API: data,
            id: widgetId
        }
    }
}
```

Your resulting reducer will look something like this:

```
{
   widgets: {
      widget-1: {
        API: 'api-1'
      },
      widget-2: {
        API: 'api-2'
      },
      ...
   }

}
```